# Checkbox Validation Without Arrow Functions using Svelte

Tags: svelte

I wanted to know if it's possible to have the code run the same way but without using arrow functions. I'm trying to make the code more easier to understand by writing it with basic concepts I already know. I would still like the code to run exactly the same by saving the colors to local storage and changing the string as the user checks/unchecks an option. I'm having trouble getting my version to run the same way. Here is the code:

This is the original version:

```
 <script>
        const colours = {
            blue: false,
            red: false,
            green: false,
            purple: false
        };

  $: colourString = Object.keys(colours).filter(c => colours[c]).join(',');
    $: {
    console.log(colourString);
    localStorage.setItem("colors", colourString);
    }
</script>

{#if !Object.keys(colours).filter(c => !!colours[c]).length}
<p>please pick a color</p>
{:else}
String of colours being saved is: {colourString}
{/if}

<div id="container">
    <label>Select the colors you like:</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.blue}>
    <label>Blue</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.red}>
    <label>Red</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.green}>
    <label>Green</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.purple}>
    <label>Purple</label><br><br>
</div>
```

Changed version:

```
        <script>
        const colours = {
            blue: false,
            red: false,
            green: false,
            purple: false
        };

function myFunction (color) {
  switch (color) {
    case 'blue': 
            return color.blue;
   case 'red': 
            return color.red;
   case 'green':
            return color.green;
    case 'purple':
            return color.purple;
  }
}

    $: {
    console.log(colourString);
    //localStorage.setItem("colors", colourString);
    }
</script>

<p>please pick a color</p>
<p>String of colours being saved is: {color}</p>

<div id="container">
    <label>Select the colors you like:</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.blue}>
    <label>Blue</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.red}>
    <label>Red</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.green}>
    <label>Green</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" bind:checked={colours.purple}>
    <label>Purple</label><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how this works :

```
$: colourString = Object.keys(colours).filter(c => colours[c]).join(',');
    $: {
    console.log(colourString);
    localStorage.setItem("colors", colourString);
    }
```

Let me break it down, first you bind a string colourString to any change.

```
$: colourString =
```

Then you get all keys from the const object (blue, red..)

```
Object.keys(colours)
```

Then LOOP over the keys (basically a foreach) returning an array of all values that are true

```
.filter(
```

Then in the foreach, run a function that retuns a bool:

```
c => colours[c]
```

This is the same as :

```
function(color) {
    return colours[color];
}
```

And you could write it also like this:

```
function(color) {
  switch color {
    case 'blue': return colours.blue;
    case 'red': return colours.red;
    case 'green': return colours.green;
    case 'purple': return colours.purple;
  }
}
```

The last step: .join(','); is another loop, that loops over the result array from the filter function joining all keys in a "," separated string.

//edit

```
$: {
    console.log(colourString);
    //localStorage.setItem("colors", colourString);
}
```

Here is another way to write it:

```
$: {
  let colorString = "";
  for (var key in colours) {
    colorString += getColor(key) ? key : "";
  }
  console.log(colorString);

  function getColor(color) {
    switch (color) {
      case 'blue'  : return colours.blue;
      case 'red'   : return colours.red;
      case 'green' : return colours.green;
      case 'purple': return colours.purple;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I modified the code in my question to use the switch case instead since that was easier to understand for me. I'm getting an unexpected token 9:8 error but I'm having trouble understanding why. Could you please take a look at my updated question? @devzero

Comment: You have to define and bind colorString: $: colourString = Object.keys(colours).filter(c => myFunction(c)).join(',');

Comment: I'm still getting confused when trying to follow the examples. I can't seem to wrap my head around changing the code without the arrow functions like I wanted. But I understood the switch case one the best so I'll keep that for reference and just keep trying, thanks! @devzero